# Galois Group of a complex polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

How I can find $|Gal(f(x))|$ with $f(x)=x^2+2ix+1$? I know that roots are $x_1=-i+i\sqrt{2},x_2=-i-i\sqrt{2}$

If $L:=\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2)$, then $$[L:\mathbb{Q}]=[L:\mathbb{Q}(x_1)][\mathbb{Q}(x_1):\mathbb{Q}]$$

Therefore $Gal(f(x))=Gal(L:\mathbb{Q})$

This is correct?

Comment: Note that $f$ is not a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$. Most authors require that when defining $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$ (viewed as the Galois group of the extension of $\mathbb Q$ 'defined by $f$').

Comment: +1 ah, Carlos... el ResearchGate está en https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Janmarqz_Bobadilla2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your results, $L=Q(\sqrt2,i)$, the Galois group contains $f_1(i)=-i, f_1(\sqrt2)=\sqrt2), f_2(i)=i,f_2(\sqrt2)=-\sqrt2$ and $f_1,f_2$ generates a group $G$ of order four which is $[L:Q]$ so the Galois group is $G=Z/2\times Z/2$.

Comment: In my textbook the answer is $|Gal(f(x))|=2$, but I'm not sure

Comment: Are you looking for the Galois group over $Q$ or the Galois group over $Q[i]$ ?

Comment: In fact, the text does not mention it, so it causes me problems to solve this exercise.

Comment: This is excellent evidence that authors of textbooks can make mistakes just like you and me.

Answer (score 4):

When you are talking about Galois group of a polynomial, you must be given where the polynomial lives in. The definition says that the Galois group of $f(x)$ over $F$ is the Galois group of the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$. So here $f(x)\notin \mathbb{Q}[x]$, but it is in $\mathbb{Q}(i)[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$. So you should check the question to see which field you are working on. If it is $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ for example, then the Galois group of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(i,x_{1},x_{2})/\mathbb{Q}(i))$.